# Drupal: Incorrect use of t()?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I want to wrap a word in `<strong>` tags. Is it correct to do that right in the `t()` call, or am I supposed to do it some other way?

```
$help = '<p>' . t("Does this sample data look right for node type %node_type? If not, use your browser's <strong>back</strong> button to fix it on the previous page.", array('%node_type' => $_SESSION[NODE_TYPE_KEY])) . '</p>';
```

Also, what about just dropped variables directly into `t()`, like this?

```
    foreach ($term_info['term_fields'] as $vocab) {
        $options[$vocab] = t($vocab); // TODO: incorrect use of t()?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your questions are answered in the Drupal API documentation at http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6. A short summary:

You can wrap a word in html tags if you really must. Quote:

> HTML markup within translation strings
>   is allowed, but should be avoided if
>   possible.

It is *not* allowed to drop variables into t() like you do in your code snippet. Quote:

> Because t() is designed for handling
>   code-based strings, in almost all
>   cases, the actual string and not a
>   variable must be passed through t().